# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError when using Qute TypeSafe Templates with Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, quarkus, quarkus-qute

When trying to use [Quarkus Qute Typesafe Templates](https://quarkus.io/guides/qute#type-safe-templates) with Kotlin (converting the static class into an object as per the code below), I run into an UnsatisfiedLinkError at runtime.

The code at issue:

```kotlin
@Path("/subscriber")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
class SubscriberResource {

    @CheckedTemplate
    object Templates {
        external fun new(): TemplateInstance
    }

    @GET
    fun get(): TemplateInstance {
        return Templates.new()
    }
}
```

with the template being available in `resources/templates/SubscriberResource/new.html`.

The project builds fine, but when I attempt to open the view, I get the exception given below.

I've also tried making the object a `companion` object, but it didn't help.

Any idea what's missing?

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'io.quarkus.qute.TemplateInstance com.app.subscriber.SubscriberResource$Templates.new()'
> at com.app.subscriber.SubscriberResource$Templates.new(Native Method)
> at com.app.subscriber.SubscriberResource.get(SubscriberResource.kt:23)
> at com.app.subscriber.SubscriberResource_Subclass.get$$superaccessor1(SubscriberResource_Subclass.zig:189)
> at com.app.subscriber.SubscriberResource_Subclass$$function$$6.apply(SubscriberResource_Subclass$$function$$6.zig:29)
> at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:54)
> at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.proceed(InvocationInterceptor.java:63)
> at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.monitor(InvocationInterceptor.java:49)
> at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor_Bean.intercept(InvocationInterceptor_Bean.zig:521)
> at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:41)
> at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:41)
> at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:32)
> at com.app.subscriber.SubscriberResource_Subclass.get(SubscriberResource_Subclass.zig:147)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:170)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:130)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:643)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:507)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$2(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:457)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:459)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:419)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:393)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:68)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:492)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:261)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:161)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:164)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:247)
> at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.RequestDispatcher.service(RequestDispatcher.java:73)
> at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.dispatch(VertxRequestHandler.java:138)
> at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.access$000(VertxRequestHandler.java:41)
> at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler$1.run(VertxRequestHandler.java:93)
> at io.quarkus.runtime.CleanableExecutor$CleaningRunnable.run(CleanableExecutor.java:231)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
> at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2415)
> at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1452)
> at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
> at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
> at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)
> Resulted in: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'io.quarkus.qute.TemplateInstance com.app.subscriber.SubscriberResource$Templates.new()'
> at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:106)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:372)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:218)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:519)
> ... 18 more

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally figured out a solution, adding `@JvmStatic` to the external object function solves it:

```kotlin
    @CheckedTemplate
    object Templates {
        @JvmStatic
        external fun new(): TemplateInstance
    }
```