# Type-safe Qute template with Kotlin data classes

Tags: kotlin, quarkus, quarkus-qute

I'm learning Quarkus and Qute with Kotlin, but I can't get type-safe templates to work.

The data I'm feeding into my template is of type `Paginated<out T>` (where `Paginated` adds information about total page count, current page, etc.).

The [documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/qute-reference#typesafe_templates) says you can let your controller return

> a Java record that implements `io.quarkus.qute.TemplateInstance`

And I was hoping that I could do the same thing with a Kotlin data class. I prefer that over invoking an `@JvmStatic external fun` method since the latter is a lot harder to write unit tests for.

Anyway, I wrote a controller that returns this data class instance:

```kotlin
@GET @Path("/list") @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
fun list(@QueryParam("pageIndex") pageIndex: Int = 0): TemplateInstance {
  // work your magic
  return ExampleListTemplate(
    Paginated(
      currentPage = 0,
      pageCount = 1,
      items = listOf("example")
    )
  )
}

@CheckedTemplate(basePath = "example")
data class ExampleListTemplate(val data: Paginated<String>): TemplateInstance
```

But when I request that page, I get a stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at io.quarkus.qute.TemplateInstance.getTemplate(TemplateInstance.java:142)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.qute.runtime.TemplateResponseFilter.filter(TemplateResponseFilter.java:45)
```

The actual one is a lot longer but I believe this is the relevant part.

Is this supposed to work? If so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I know you can also use `@JvmStatic external fun` (as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67381526/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-when-using-qute-typesafe-templates-with-kotlin)) but I dislike that approach for testability reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotating a Kotlin data class with `@JvmRecord` tells the Kotlin compiler to mark the class as a Java record and generate relevant `toString`/`equals`/`hashCode` methods.

It turns out that this is also enough for Quarkus to leverage that Kotlin data class as a `TemplateInstance`.

With a data class written like so:

```kotlin
@CheckedTemplate(basePath = "example")
@JvmRecord
data class List(val data: Paginated<String>): TemplateInstance
```

Quarkus will look for a template **example/list.html**.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin data classes are not supported yet. Feel free to create a [feature request](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues) or even send a pull request ;-).

Comment: Thanks. It's not the answer I hoped for, but it provides a perfect explanation of why it doesn't work. I've created [#38194](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/38194) to propose the idea.